# Setting user data just for one commit

Tags: git

I don't have the git user data set:

```shell
$ git commit -m '...'

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <...>) not allowed
```

If I run these commands my user data will be set globally. I only want to have the user data set for one commit.

Is there any argument that I can pass to `git commit` to set the user data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--author` flag will set the author, but you must also set the committer name and email.

There is no command-line flag for this but git will use environment variables if they are set: `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`.

Assuming an sh/bash-style shell:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='A U Thor' \
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='author@example.example' \
git commit --author 'A U Thor <author@example.example>' ...
```

should do it.

Or, you can just set these in your git global configuration, then remove them (use `git config --global -e` to run your favorite editor on the file, if you don't want to fiddle with `git config --unset`).

Edit: or, you can configure them temporarily with `git -c name=value`, e.g.:

```
git -c user.name='A U Thor' -c user.email=author@example.example commit ...
```

Note that (as with the environment variables) this will override any file-configuration values.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the author using the `--author` option:

```
git commit --author="Corey Ward <corey@notmyemail.com>" -m "..."
```

Comment: Hmm.. I still get `Please tell me who you are.` message. Any other ideas?

Comment: @IonicăBizău this is the answer to your question about setting the user data for one commit - but git still requires you to have *some data* in the global configuration as well, even if it doesn't use it for commit data.

Comment: @eis What would it be the solution if I don't want to set global user data or to edit `~/.gitconfig` file?

Comment: You can set it for the repository you're committing to, just remove the `--global` option when you run `git config`.

Comment: @coreyward I don't want that... I want to *set the user data just for **one commit***...

Comment: So set it for one commit, then remove it, or use @torek's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Author can be overridden by using the --author option

see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html

Comment: I get the same message... `Please tell me who you are.`

Comment: It is quite strange, for me it works with `git commit --author="test author <mail@example.org>" -m "test commit"`